# .NET FormsAuthentication and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated combination not working

Tags: c#, .net, forms, authentication, web-config

I'm trying to create a simple setup where the user navigates to a page and if they're not authenticated, taken to a login page.  If the user enters the correct username and password, he/she is taken back to the first page where they have the ability to add data to a SQL database.  Unfortunately as of now, when the user is authenticated, they get bounced from the first page back to the login page (e.g. the user isn't being authenticated).  Here's what I have for code:

The applicable code in first page (where the user can enter data)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*Make sure the user is authenticated.  If not, redirect them to the Login page*/
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    else
        LabelMsg.Text = "Authenticated: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
}//end Page_Load()
```

The applicable code in login page:

```
 using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                sda.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView GridViewBookList = new GridView();
                GridViewBookList.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewBookList.DataBind();
                if (GridViewBookList.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin", true);
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("admin", true);

                }
                else
                    LabelMsg.Text = "Incorrect username or password";
            }
```

Web.Config piece

```
<location path="~/whatsnew/add-newbook.aspx">
<!--Unauthenticated users cannot access this page-->
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <!--.NEWBOOK is the name of the cookie used in authorization-->
    <forms loginUrl="~/whatsnew/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" requireSSL="true" name=".NEWBOOK"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="admin"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check Request.IsAuthenticated in your code. If you would like to use the HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated, in my experience I have had to set it by saying something like the following in my login page:

```
string username = "My username";
string[] roles = new string[] {"Role1", "Role2"};

HttpContext.Current.User = 
   new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're doing simple forms authentication. Have you tried adding WebSecurity.Login before you set the cookie?

```
WebSecurity.Login("admin", pwd, True);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin", true);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("admin", true);
```